# Functionality of Prism modules in interested classes (Xamarin Foirms + Prism)

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

**Good day!**

---

**UPDATE**

I don’t understand how to access the functionality of the Prism module from the class using the module logic.

**Questions:**

- How do I get access to the implementation of the IServiceA functionality (defined in the module) in PageAViewModel, which I forget to do?
- How can I manage the life of ModuleA / ServiceA if I want to use this functionality on a number of different countries, without loading the module every time (scenario - I call ModuleA / ServiceA when loading an application, use it on PageA / PageB / PageC, after using it I unload it) .

Thank you all for any answers! 
Have a nice day!
/Sorry for google translate/

[image: Logic]

Comment: Edited my answer... all of this is very basic stuff, though, I _really_ recommend a few weeks of reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules of a prism application are for modularizing the code base. They have nothing to do with views or view models, but rather splitting the application up into components that can be independently developed and tested and replaced. How you split your application is up to you.

Probably you should review the [documentation chapter about modularity](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Modules.html)...

Edit: about the concret questions:

> How do I get access to the implementation of the IServiceA functionality (defined in the module) in PageAViewModel, which I forget to do?

You create a constructor parameter of type `IService` and prism will provide you with the registered implementation:

```
internal class PageAViewModel
{
    public PageAViewModel( IService service )
    {
        service.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

> How can I manage the life of ModuleA / ServiceA if I want to use this functionality on a number of different countries, without loading the module every time

You cannot and need not manage the lifetime of `ModuleA`, prism takes care of that. As for, `ServiceA` you chose a lifetime when registering:

- `containerRegistry.Register<IService, ServiceA>()` creates a new service instance for each page
- `containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IService, ServiceA>()` create a single service instance for all the pages

Comment: Unfortunately, this documentation was compiled long ago, is not supported, and in certain places it does not have direct recommendations for Xamarin.Forms - it is often necessary to guess. I re-read it again and still did not understand how to be. Please explain if you have an answer to my task. Thank.

Comment: The concept of modularity in prism hasn't changed in ages. If you have more specific problems, you should update your question.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for clarifications and help - sometimes you just need to see an example once in order to understand a concept. Thank you!